# How to access IIS: drive on remote machine via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName "UABEP1" -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools }

Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (IIS:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : UABEP1
```

Running the command locally on the remote machine returns the list of app pools. Is there a security setting that must be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting to load the WebAdministration module:

```
{ Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools }
```